# How to calculate number of leap years between two dates in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to calculate the number of leap years between the hire date of the employee and the current date (on hr.employees table in Oracle SQL Developer). How to do this?

Comment: Suppose the employee is hired on 2000-01-01; does 2000 count as one of the leap years?  What about 2000-03-01 and 2000-12-31?  Suppose the current year is 2016 (or 2020 if you prefer), and the current date is 2016-01-01, 2016-03-01, 2016-12-31 — do you count 2016 as one of the leap years?  Are you really counting the number of leap days that have occurred during their employment?

Comment: Two more significant dates to consider: 2000-02-29 and 2016-02-29.  When you know the answer to these boundary issues, the rest is relatively straight-forward, inasmuch as any date calculation is ever 'straight-forward'.  There are few more vexing areas of computation.

Comment: Do you want to count the number of *leap days* or *leap years*?  If the latter, how do you define what happens if someone is hired on, say Mar 15th versus Feb 15th of a leap year?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A leap year consists of 366 days.  I assume a "leap year" between two dates consists of all the days from Jan 1 to Dec 31 of a year with Feb 29th.

Based on this understanding, there is a pretty simple solution.

- Count the number of days between the Jan 1 of the year following the hire date and Jan 1 of the year of the end date.
- Count the number of years between those two dates.
- Subtract the difference between the days and the number of years * 365

Happily, built-in functions do most of the work.

This results in:

```
   (trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY') -
    trunc(hiredate + interval '1' year, 'YYYY') -
    365 * (extract(year from sysdate) - extract(year from hiredate) - 1)
   ) as num_years
```

It is a little trickier to count *leap days* but that is not what the question is asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can reuse the code Oracle has already written: just check if creating a leap day raises an exception:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2016-02-29','YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL;
29.02.2016
```

but

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2018-02-29','YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL;
ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
```

So you just have to count the exceptions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_leap_years (p_from DATE, p_to DATE) RETURN NUMBER 
IS
  number_of_leap_days NUMBER := 0;
  date_not_valid EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(date_not_valid, -1839);
BEGIN
  FOR y IN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p_from) .. EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p_to) LOOP
    DECLARE
      d DATE;
    BEGIN
      d := TO_DATE(to_char(y,'fm0000')||'-02-29', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
      IF p_from < d AND d < p_to THEN
        number_of_leap_days := number_of_leap_days + 1;
      END IF;
    EXCEPTION WHEN date_not_valid THEN 
      NULL;
    END;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN number_of_leap_days;
END count_leap_years;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will allow you to select numbers, in this case, from 1 to 2999.

```
    Select Rownum year
    From dual
    Connect By Rownum <= 2999
```

Something like this will allow you to check if a specific year is a leap year or not

```
CASE WHEN ((MOD(YEAR, 4) = 0 AND (MOD(YEAR, 100) <> 0)) OR MOD(year, 400) = 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as isLeapYear
```

Now you just need to add the filtering and the sum of the leap years.

```
Select sum(isLeapYear)
from (
    Select year, CASE WHEN ((MOD(YEAR, 4) = 0 AND (MOD(YEAR, 100) <> 0)) OR MOD(year, 400) = 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as isLeapYear
FROM (
    Select Rownum year
    From dual
    Connect By Rownum <= 2999
    ) a
    Where a.year >= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE %DateStart%) and a.year <= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE %DateEnd%)
) b
```

This can be really improved in terms of performance, but like this I think its easier do understand what each step is doing and then you can decompose it into what you really want and expect.

Comment: You are right, I updated the response to work correctly on Oracle SQL.
Functions Values and Year are not available in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LEAP_YEARS(EMP_ID IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS 

HIRE_YEAR NUMBER:=0;
SYS_YEAR  NUMBER:=0;
NUMBER_LEAP_YEARS NUMBER:=0;

BEGIN
 SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIRE_DATE) INTO HIRE_YEAR
 FROM EMPLOYEE
 WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = EMP_ID;

 SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE()) INTO SYS_YEAR
 FROM DUAL;

 FOR IDX IN HIRE_YEAR..SYS_YEAR LOOP
    IF MOD(IDX,4)=0 THEN
        NUMBER_LEAP_YEARS := NUMBER_LEAP_YEARS  + 1;
    END IF;
 END LOOP;

RETURN NUMBER_LEAP_YEARS;
END;
```

I tested it on a toy example and it works. Maybe you need to improve it (hint: maybe it needs some exceptions and it assume that hire_date < sysdate).

Then you can use it as:

```
SELECT LEAP_YEARS(E.EMPLOYEE_ID) FROM EMPLOYEE E;
```